# rails association limit record based on an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, primary-key, limit

As you can see in the schema below, a user can create courses and submit a time and a video (like youtube) for it, via course_completion.
What I would like to do is to limit to 1 a course completion for a user, a given course and based one the attribute "pov" (point of view)
For instance for the course "high altitude race" a user can only have one course_completion with pov=true and/or one with pov=false
That mean when creating course completion I have to check if it already exist or not, and when updating I have to check it also and destroy the previous record (or update it).

I don't know if I'm clear enough on what I want to do, it may be because I have no idea how to do it properly with rails 4 (unless using tons of lines of codes avec useless checks).
I was thinking of putting everything in only one course_completion (normal_time, pov_time, normal_video, pov_video) but I don't really like the idea :/

Can someone help me on this ?
Thanks for any help !

Here are my classes:

```
class CourseCompletion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video_info

  # attribute pov
  # attribute time
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :course_completions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use validates uniqueness with scoping [Rails - Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) .

```
class CourseCompletion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video_info

  validates :course, uniqueness: { scope: :pov, message: "only one course per pov" }

  # attribute pov
  # attribute time
end
```